# Admin Panel 404 Error after login

Tags: php, users, login

well i've created a custom login page (NOT customizing orignal login page) and use the code below to log in users:

```
if($_POST){
    if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $creds = array(
            'user_login'    => $_POST['username'],
            'user_password' => $_POST['password'],
            'remember'      => true
            );
        $login = wp_signon( $creds, false );
        if ( is_wp_error( $login ) ) {
            $exiturl = get_site_url().'/account/auth';
            header("Location: $exiturl");
            exit();
        }
} else {
    echo "access denied";
}
```

the logging process works just fine, BUT if **an admin user** logs in via this form they can not access admin panel. they login successfully and **can surf the website** but they **can't access admin panel** to do anything (writing, editing, changing settings, ....)!

is there something that i'm missing? do i need to set any cookies or something?!

Comment: "they can not access the admin panel" - what does this mean exactly? What happens when they take which particular actions exactly?  Also, you're passing `false` to the `wp_signon()` function - why?

Comment: thank you, i figured it was all becuase of "false" in wp_signon()

Comment: I suspected it might be causing you trouble if you're using HTTPS on the admin side

Answer (score 0):

I should have changed `false` to `true` in the line `$login = wp_signon( $creds, false );`

so the final working code is

```
if($_POST){
    if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $creds = array(
            'user_login'    => $_POST['username'],
            'user_password' => $_POST['password'],
            'remember'      => true
            );
        $login = wp_signon( $creds, true);
        if ( is_wp_error( $login ) ) {
            $exiturl = get_site_url().'/account/auth';
            header("Location: $exiturl");
            exit();
        }
} else {
    echo "access denied";
}
```